# where do I include wp_head() in wordpress plugins?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have this javascript code that I am including in my plugin using `wp_enqueue_script()` finction. Some forks told me that i need to add `wp_head()` for it to work... So where can I add it? Or is there any other solution that I can make this javascript file work in the plugin?
thanks.

code is here.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WP Test Plugin.
Plugin URI: http://wplugins.com
Description: A plugin that test javascript.
Author: Ronny Kibet.
Author URI: http://wplugins.com
Version: 1.0
 */

 //globals

 $floating_options = get_option('floating_settings');

 //enable settings.

function popupthis() {
$src = plugins_url('/includes/links.js', __FILE__);
wp_register_script( 'links', $src );
wp_enqueue_script( 'links' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','popupthis');
?>
```

Comment: what JavaScript code? there isn't any in your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

wp_head() goes in the header.php file of your theme.

Comment: well basically, but what If I change my theme?

Comment: you include it in every theme.  It's suppose to be there.  and wp_foot() should be before every </body> tag you use.  If not you are creating incomplete themes

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is theme's responsability to call wp_head function and you, as a plugin developer, shouldn't worry about this.

In case it's missing (so your plugin works with TwentyTen and doesn't with any), call wp_head() just before closing  tag, usually it is in theme's header.php file.